# Specific color from string

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, colors

i have a uitableview, which gets populated by a pulling data from a website, so there is a new string for every cell. To that, i want to have show a HEX for the user, based on the text in the cell.

I have tryed myself to make it, without luck, but luckly found a javascript script which does what i try to do. This script, i now need to convert to obj-c, i have tryed it myself, but failed. I hope to get some help.

javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/sUK45/

My try in obj-c (here the strings aint based on the data from the web, but just an array):

```
unichar hash = 0;

        NSArray *strings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"MA", @"Ty", @"Ad", @"ER", nil];

        for (int i = 0; i < [[strings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] length]; i++) {
            hash = [[strings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] characterAtIndex:i] + ((hash < 5) - hash);
        }

        NSString *colour = @"#";
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            int value = (hash >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF;
            colour = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", colour, value];
        }

        NSLog(@"%@", colour);
```

But the data i get, aint a useable HEX - NSlog:

```
#2432550
#3600
#3400
#1200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is not the only one mistake. Change

```
hash = [[strings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] characterAtIndex:i] + ((hash < 5) - hash);
```

to

```
hash = [[strings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] characterAtIndex:i] + ((hash << 5) - hash);
```

UPDATE:

Also change

```
colour = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", colour, value];
```

to

```
colour = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%02x", colour, (unsigned int)value];
```

UPDATE2:

I have fixed one more error and simplified code:

```
unsigned int hash = 0;

NSArray *strings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"MA", @"Ty", @"Ad", @"ER", nil];
NSString *string = [strings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    hash = [string characterAtIndex:i] + ((hash << 5) - hash);
}

NSString *color = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%06x", hash % 0x1000000];
NSLog(@"%@", color);
```

Comment: Well it changes some, but some of the HEXs are still to short or long

#14890
#165100
#6780
 #17380

Comment: @magnuskahr I have updated the answer, please check.

Comment: It works perfectly! but it seams like it only makes colors in the range of green and blue, any idea how it would be possible to make a vary by a range of all colors?

Comment: @magnuskahr Have you noticed that I have changed `unichar hash` to `unsigned int hash` in last version? It should solve this problem.

Comment: No sorry, i missed that :-) You are right, it works perfectly, thank you very mutch for your help!